# Diferente ejecución que en una ventana interactiva

Tags: python, date, hilos, shell, timer

Estoy creando una función 'repeat' para repetir una función varias veces (obviamente). Esta función admite la cantidad de veces que se va a repetir, cada cuanto se va a hacer, la función, y los *args y **kwargs.
Haciendo pruebas con la función print, cuando le paso end="" como kwarg y le doy a 'Run Python File', el programa printea los args después de (cantidad de veces-1 * cada cuanto) segundos, en vez de printear de uno en uno, es decir, **me los printea todos a la vez**, cosa que cuando le paso únicamente el kwarg sep o el kwarg end="\n" no ocurre.

He estado revisando mi código y no encuentro el fallo, así que se me ha ocurrido que en vez de ejecutarlo mediante 'Run Python File', podría ejecutarlo mediante 'Run Current File in Interactive Window' (simplemente por probar) y, al hacerlo, he conseguido el resultado que quería y que esperaba del programa.

Explicación ~: (hacer funcion(args, kwargs), esperar(segundos))*cantidad de veces
Output con 'Run Python File': espera todos los segundos y después printea todo
Output con 'Run Current File in Interactive Window': print... después de varios segundos print...
**Os he puesto en comentario las partes del código que no tienen que ver con el problema**

```
import threading
from functools import partial
import msvcrt
import time

#def input_with_timeout(prompt, timeout):
#    print(prompt, end='', flush=True)
#    start_time = time.time()
#    input_data = ''
#    while time.time()-start_time<timeout:
#        if msvcrt.kbhit():
#            char = msvcrt.getwch()
#            if char == '\r':
#                print()
#                return input_data
#            elif char == '\b':
#                input_data = input_data[:-1]
#                print('\b \b', end='', flush=True)
#            else:
#                input_data += char
#                print(char, end='', flush=True)
#        if time.time() - start_time >= timeout:
#            print()
#            return input_data

class Threads(threading.Thread):
    '''Clase que hereda threading.Thread'''
    def __init__(self, interval: float, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self.interval=interval
        self.function=function
        self.args=args[0]
        self.kwargs=kwargs['kwargs']

    def start_thread(self, pos: int):  #, inputs: list):
        #if self.function==input:
        #    now=time.time()
        #    function_timeout=partial(input_with_timeout, self.args[0][0], self.interval)
        #    x=function_timeout()
        #    inputs.append(x)

        #else: # indent below
        self.t=threading.Timer(self.interval*pos, self.function, self.args, kwargs=self.kwargs)
        self.t.start()
        self.t.join()


def repeat(times: int, interval: float, function: callable, *args, **kwargs):
    #inputs=[]
    for _ in range(0, times):
        t=Threads(interval, function, args, kwargs=kwargs)
        t.start_thread(_)  #, inputs)

    #return inputs if function==input else None
repeat(3, 2, print, 'Hola mundo', '', sep='!', end='')    # 
print()
repeat(3, 2, print, 'Hola mundo', '', sep='!', end='\n')  #
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usás print, en realidad y sin entrar mucho en detalles, los datos son guardados en un buffer interno (es decir, en memoria) hasta que se considera que deben ser enviados a la consola todos juntos. Esto es para evitar hacer llamadas innecesarias al sistema.

Por default, esto ocurre cuando se envía un salto de linea (`\n`) al buffer.

Si usas python 3.3 o superior, debes pasar a cada print el argumento `flush=True`. Esto le dice a Python "después de escribir esto en el buffer, envialo a la consola". Esto te será sencillo usando tu función repeat.

De lo contrario, podrías importar el modulo sys y usar `sys.stdout.flush()` luego de cada print, donde stdout es una especie de "archivo falso" que usa de intermediario print para escribir en la consola. Aunque no puedo comprobar que funcione.

Referencia en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7127162/12913664